# first date is updating only after i select date 2nd time in my modal

Tags: angularjs, cordova, datepicker, ionic-framework

When I select a date or time it will not immediately change in my modal. Changes will reflect only after i select date second time(first selected date gets updated).
Any clues??

```
<div class="item  item-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
             <i class="icon ion-ios7-calendar-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
             <span ng-model="bookCtrl.Start_Booking_Date" ng-click="showDatePicker()">{{ dateSelected }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
             <i class="icon ion-ios7-clock-outline placeholder-icon right"></i>
             <span class="right"  ng-click="showTimePicker()">{{ timeSelected }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My showDatePicker() function:

$scope.showDatePicker=function(){

```
$cordovaDatePicker.show({
date: new Date(),
mode: 'date',
allowOldDates : false
```

}).then(function (date) {

// $scope.display.completionDate = $filter('date')(new Date(date));

```
if(!isNaN(date.getDate()))
{
    $scope.dateSelected=date.getDate()+"-"+(1+date.getMonth())+"-"+date.getFullYear();
    b.Start_Booking_Date=$scope.dateSelected;
}
```

});

};

Comment: whats the relation between `Start_Booking_Date` and `dateSelected`, your ng-model, what you are printing do differ

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Sounds like you need a `$scope.$apply()` somewhere to trigger the digest loop.

Comment: Is your second span missing the ng-model? probably copy paste error, not related to issue. Can you also share the showDatePicker() and showTimePicker function please?

Comment: check my controller code..

Answer (score 0):

In the then() of your promise, wrap the code in $scope.$apply() to assure that angular knows about the change.

```
$scope().$apply(function(){
  $scope.dateSelected=date.getDate()+"-"+(1+date.getMonth())+"-"+date.getFullYear();
  b.Start_Booking_Date=$scope.dateSelected;
});
```